# "Statistics": How many of these begin and end with the letter "S"?

Tags: statistics, permutations

> How many distinct permutations are there of the letters
>   in the word “**statistics”?** How many of these begin
>   and end with the letter s?

The first part of the question I do understand. You have to use permutation with identical items. This is based on the number of letters.

$$\binom{10}{3,3,1,2,1} = 50400$$

Yet for the second part I am confused as to what the directions means. It says that how many letters begin and ends with letters  **s** so does one eliminate $2$ s and calculate this problem normally?

BONUS:
 If so using a similar example how does one find out if how many of these begin and end with the letters **m** for the word
 **"mathematicsman"**?

Comment: You're correct - you can remove 2 s's from "statistics" and find the distinct permutations of "tatistic". For your bonus question, there is only 1 s in "mathematicsman".

Comment: So for that example do you remove only one s or two s?

Comment: In your second example, there are 0 ways, since you cannot have a rearrangement of "mathematicsman" that starts and ends with "s", since there is only one "s".

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake it is m. For mathematicsman.

Comment: Then, in the second example we also remove two m's and consider the permutations of "athematicsan" (removing two "m"s). Of course, it doesn't matter which two "m"s we remove.

Comment: @user2825632 Why do you remove two m? The first letter is m and the last is n thus only one m should be removed.

Comment: We can start by moving two m's (since one "m" should occur at the beginning and one at the end) to their positions before doing any permutation calculations. Then the word that remains after we move them to their positions is "athematicsan".

Comment: I think I see what you did you removed the third from the last word in mathematicsman. See when I read the end I assume the last letter in the word mathematicsman which is n, but I guess the question meant third from the last. I guess it means the last m but not the very last just the one that is the most farthest.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding - we could also remove the first and second m's to find permutations of "atheaticsman". The original locations of any of the letters don't matter. When you get a "how many distinct permutations of ___ exist?", you can take the word and split it up into counts of the unique letters and solve it from there (e.g. restate the question as "how many permutations of  3 Ms, 3 A's, etc exist?"). The original word and the order of its letters is unimportant.

Comment: So for example the word "matheatican" has only 1 m that means that the word would be atheatican. In the case I was talking about in the above.

Comment: Yep - that sounds right.

Comment: So you remove only 1 m. for "matheatican".

Comment: No - technically, there are no words that satisfy their requirements of starting and ending with "m" if you start with "matheatican", since it only has  1 "m" and you shouldn't be able to reuse letters. I'm not sure how they expect you to handle that situation. (I would probably say there are 0 words.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my, such confusion! Let's try to simplify this, yet keep its essence.

Instead of *statistics*, let's use *stats*. There are 30 unique
arrangements, of which 3 have *s* at each end:
$$ \frac{5!}{2!\,2!} = 30\; \; \text{and} \; \; 3!/2! = 3.$$
So we can get the second number by removing *s* from each end
and dealing with what remains.

This means that in a random permutation. the probability of
getting an *s* at each end, should to 0.1.

In the simulation program below, I have avoided the messiness
of dealing with character strings in R, by substituting numbers
for letters in `stats` (1 represents *s*). A million random
permutations ought to give 2-place accuracy, so the answer
substantially matches the theoretical value.

```
 stats = c(1,1,2,2,3)
 n = length(stats)
 m = 10^6; x = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
  perm = sample(stats,n)
  x[i] = (perm[1]==1 & perm[n]==1) }
 mean(x)
 ## 0.099806
```

Now let's use `mamam` instead of `mathematicsman`. Again here, we can
use the standard method find $\frac{5!}{3!\cdot 2!} =10$ as the number of *unrestricted, distinguishable* permutations. If we ignore two of the (indistingusihable) `m`'s, then we
have the 3 arrangements of `ama`. So the probability
a random permutation has *m*'s at both ends should be $3/10 = 0.3.$ The simulation below
confirms this.

```
 mamam = c(1,1,1,2,2)
 n = length(mamam)
 m = 10^6; x = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
   perm = sample(mamam,n)
   x[i] = (perm[1]==1 & perm[n]==1) }
 mean(x)
 ## 0.300217
```

Comment: Thanks to @john for suggested edit. Although I and two reviewers disagree with the exact edit, I did take this opportunity to add some details and to simplify the language and formatting, which I hope makes the argument a little clearer.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is (3 choose 1) times (9 choose 2,3,1,2,1). 
My reasoning is that you force an 's' at the front of your word in three different ways and then shuffle the rest of the letters around.

Answer (score -1):

Since 'statistics' must start and end with an s this reduces the total permutations of statistics (-tatistic-) to 8!. For distinct permutations - you need to account for the 3! ways you can rearrange the 3xt in -tatistic- and the 2xi (2!).